# Why Django API showing ambiguous behavior on heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, pagination

Currently i am using Django restful api's. i am doing pagination. my api for pagination is

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getAll_Mobiles(request):
    try:

        Mobile_all = Mobile_DB.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(Mobile_all, 10)

        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:

            users = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:

            users = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999),
        # deliver last page of results.
            users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        serializer_context = {'request': request}
        serializer = Mobile_Serializer(users,many=True,context=serializer_context)
        # res = serializer.data
        # res.update('pages_count:', paginator.num_pages())
        #return Response(res)

        return Response({
    'totalItems':paginator._get_count(),
    'totalPages':paginator._get_num_pages(),
    'results': serializer.data
})

    except Mobile_DB.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    pass
```

when i run it locally it gives me data in right format as i am returning it like

```
{
    "totalItems": xx,
    "totalPages": Xx,
    "results": [
        {
    }]}
```

but when i push it on heroku it gives shows different format like most of time it does not shows totalItems and total pages like it and shows only results

```
{

    "results": [
        {
    }]}
```

and sometimes it shows like

```
{
    "totalItems": 347,
    "results": [
        {
    }]}
```

on every push, it shows different results.
can somebody tell me why it showing this behavior?
I will be very thankful for this favor.